# Is there a way to load sheets with a specific regex with pandas.read_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is there a way to load sheets with a specific regex with `pandas.read_excel()` ?

Maybe with the parameter `sheet_name`
But can't figure how...

Example of regex :

```
regex_sheet = "\s*[d^D][A^a][y^Y]\D*\s*[1-9]\s*"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.ExcelFile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) to have a peek at the sheet names, then select the sheets to keep with any method (here your regex), finally load with [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import re

xl = pd.ExcelFile('filename.xlsx')

regex = re.compile('your_regex')

sheets = [n for n in xl.sheet_names if regex.match(n)]
# ['matching_sheet1', 'matching_sheet2']

dfs = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheets)
#  {'matching_sheet1': DataFrame1,
#   'matching_sheet2': DataFrame2}
```